# FindInstance nonconstant parameter

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I am trying to solve multiple instances of the same problem using FindInstance.

```
myList={}
listP={3,5,7,..}
For[v = 1, v <= Length[listP], v++, Print[v]; 
 myList = Append[myList, 
   FindInstance[a*a + b*b == listP[v] && a > 0 && b >= a, {a, b}, 
    Integers, 100000]]]
```

There is a message FindInstance : The system contains a nonconstant expression

I do not know why `listP[v]` is nonconstant. Do you ?

Comment: use `listP[[v]]` instead of `listP[v]`. Btw if you are new to Mathematica please consider reading [why to avoid `For` loops](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609).

Answer (score 1):

modifying your code to avoid `For` and `Append` (both of which are slow for lists with large number of entries):

```
listP = {3, 5, 7};
myList = Map[FindInstance[a*a + b*b == # && a > 0 && b >= a, {a, b}, Integers, 
100000] &, listP]
(* {{}, {{a -> 1, b -> 2}}, {}} *)
```